# Remove Time Stamps from PDF Comments?

Tags: pdf

Technically, it is possible to remove the `Created` and `Modified` time stamps of a comment in a PDF, as displayed in [this](http://documentgeek.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-remove-date-and-time-from-pdf.html) post. However, even for major PDF Software like Adobe there is [no option](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/remove-the-comment-time-stamp-in-a-pdf-document/m-p/5932214) to NEVER print these time stamps. My aim would be to annotate PDFs WITHOUT displaying the specific time to the end-user.

Therefore, my question: Is there a simple way (i.e. not having to edit every single file) for any PDF Software to never display time stamps of comments?

PS: I assume that the time stamp is a required field for any comment, but maybe I'm mistaken and there's actually a way.